# Abrir como administrador apenas na primeira vez em Delphi.

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Coloquei um método em meu sistema para alterar o registro fazendo com que ele inicie junto com o windows, para isso é necessário que o executável seja executado em modo de administrador. O problema é que toda vez que o sistema inicia, a aplicação abre e mostra a mensagem perguntando se o usuário deseja iniciar como administrador, o que me parece algo chato.

A pergunta que faço é: Existe como abrir a aplicação em modo de administrador apenas na primeira vez? ou talvez verificar se existe o registro no windows e se sim executar em modo normal?

Comment: http://chapmanworld.com/2015/06/08/elevated-privileges-for-delphi-applications/

Comment: Esse tipo de alteração não costuma ser bem vista. Sugiro que você verifique no seu sistema se a aplicação foi aberta como administrador, e caso não tenha sido, exibir uma mensagem alertando o usuário de que determinada função não será executada por causa dos privilégios, e solicitar que da próxima vez execute a aplicação como administrador.

Comment: Isso mesmo que fiz Victor. Acho que não tem como fazer de outra forma.

Comment: Você pode fazer com que a aplicação tente se re-executar com o perfil do administrador, e caso o usuário aceite, encerre a versão "não administrativa'. Uma vez que a aplicação esteja configurada como deseja, basta não chamar esta função de elevação. É uma solução elegante, pois só vai "incomodar" o usuário com o UAC até que ele aceite (e no caso de uma recusa, pode oferecer uma opção de não insistir, ou de lembrar de novo em N dias)

Comment: E nesse caso, você não ponha a opção no manifest. Tem que executar em runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Em project options/Application na seção Manifest File, marque a opção:

Enable Administrator Privileges que deve resolver.

Comment: Ele quer abrir elevado apenas na primeira execução. Isso não vai resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível abrir a aplicação com privilégios apenas na primeira vez se ela já carrega o *manifest* para abrir elevada. Também não interessante você iniciar a aplicação elevada e depois executar ela sem privilégios.

Talvez fosse melhor fazer o seguinte:

1. Fazer a configuração na instalação de sua aplicação.
2. Durante a execução validar se a aplicação está na inicialização e, caso negativo, avise ao usuário. Daí execute um outro processo/aplicativo para fazer essa configuração.

Comment: Melhor resposta! Apenas para complementar, você também pode usar a chave HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run ao invés da HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, assim não precisa de privilégios elevados. O único detalhe é que será válido apenas para a conta de usuário onde o programa estiver rodando. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

Como o uso vai ser ocasional, você pode implementar uma função em C para chamar pelo Delphi só quando necessitar da elevação:

```
#include "windows.h"

SHELLEXECUTEINFO lpExecInfo;
memset(&lpExecInfo, 0, sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO));

lpExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
lpExecInfo.lpFile = // aqui vai o nome do executável (no caso, o próprio aplicativo);
lpExecInfo.lpDirectory = // aqui vai o caminho no qual ele deve ser executado;
lpExecInfo.lpVerb = "runas";
lpExecInfo.lpParameters = "runasadmin";
lpExecInfo.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
lpExecInfo.fMask = 0;
lpExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;

ShellExecuteEx(&lpExecInfo); // retorna verdadeiro se o usuário aceitou
```

Neste caso, você não especifica no manifest que precisa de privilégios administrativos, e só chama a função acima no caso de precisar fazer algo como admin.

Se o resultado do `ShellExecuteEx` for verdadeiro, pode encerrar a instância atual, pois o usuário aceitou o UAC e já está rodando uma versão admin em paralelo.